# Recursively find the last edit on a file in a folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, recursion, directory

So I'm building a dropbox like app for a class and need to check every file to see if there has been a change since the app was last run. It watches a folder hosted on the root directory "~/foo". I'm working in Ubuntu and was trying to use os.walk but it wasn't even traversing the first directory, let alone find the last edits. This was the most recent code I tried

```
def checkFiles():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("~/foo"):
    print "Got here"
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(root, file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `~/foo` isn't the real path name. (`~` is a shortcut that the shell knows)

you need to use

```
os.path.expanduser("~/foo")
```

---

```
>>> help(os.path.expanduser)

Help on function expanduser in module posixpath:

expanduser(path)
    Expand ~ and ~user constructions.  If user or $HOME is unknown,
    do nothing.
```